# Google Chrome browser on Lubuntu 18.04 becomes colorless

Tags: google-chrome

In my Google Chrome browser on Lubuntu 18.04, the tone of the entire window and tabs often becomes gray, i.e. colorless. I wonder what the problem is and how to solve the problem?
Thanks

[image]

Extensions are:

[image]

Comment: Could you post a better image? Part of the top right-hand side of the browser window is missing. Also, which extensions have you installed?

Comment: The right side is just my account to syncing to. nothing else. I updated with the extensions in the browser.

Comment: @Kulfy Thanks. You are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using Text Mode extension which is causing the issue. Excerpt from [Text Mode extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text-mode/adelhekhakakocomdfejiipdnaadiiib) page:

> Declutter the web by activating Text Mode. All pages load in text form
>   (no images, animation or video) so content is easier to scan and read.
>
> ★ View text only pages
>     ★ Images, video, flash, are never loaded
>     ★ Color-free pages are easier on the eye

"Color-free pages" generally mean gray or B&W pages. Disabling the extension would solve the issue.